# PowerShell remove-item succeeds but throws exception

Tags: powershell, mercurial

I'm running the following command in a directory that is the root of a Mercurial repository. I want to delete any files and folders beginning with ".hg":

```
gci -rec -filter ".hg*" | remove-item -recurse -force
```

The strange thing, is that it does actually work, but still produces the following exception:

```
Get-ChildItem : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\temp\WSCopyTest\MyCompany.Services.DaftPunk\.hg\'.
At line:1 char:4
+ gci <<<<  -rec -filter ".hg*" | remove-item -recurse -force
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\temp\WSCopyT...es.DaftPunk\.hg:String) [Get-ChildItem], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Because the exception is thrown by `Get-ChildItem`, I suspect my understanding of the pipelining in PowerShell is flawed. Almost like `Get-ChildItem` finds an item, passes it to the next cmdlet in the pipeline, then looks for the next one? Is that how it works?

The following was supposed to be a script that would replicate the problem, but, on the same machine, it works flawlessly:

```
$repoRoot = "C:\Temp\HgDeleteTest\MyRepo"
remove-item $repoRoot -recurse -force
md $repoRoot
pushd $repoRoot
hg.exe init
add-content ShouldBeLeftBehind.txt "This is some text in a file that should be left behind once the various .hg files/directories are removed."
add-content .hgignore syntax:glob
add-content .hgignore *.dll
add-content .hgignore *.exe
hg.exe commit --addremove --message "Building test repository with one commit."
gci -rec -filter ".hg*" | remove-item -recurse -force
popd
```

Comment: Same problem here where it works on one machine, but I get this error on another.

Comment: I suspect that it might be a powershell version issue if there are 2 sets of behaviors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up separating the search from the removal. I believe my issue was to do with the way piping works by default (i.e. one item at a time) but I've not been able to build a test to check it.

In any case, the following works fine:

```
$hgObjects = gci -rec | ?{ $_.name -like ".hg*" -and $_.name -ne ".hgignore" }
remove-item $hgObjects -force -recurse
```

Using this style, the `remove-item` cmdlet gets an array of items found and works through them.

The `.hg` folder in my original example didn't have anything in it called `.hg*`, so I don't see what was going on. It felt more like it was trying to delete the folder twice, which I find very strange. I wonder if it's actually a PowerShell manifestation of this standard .NET behaviour:

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains
>   unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding,
>   modifying or deleting elements, the enumerator can be invalidated and
>   the next call to MoveNext or Reset can throw an
>   InvalidOperationException. If the collection is modified between
>   MoveNext and Current, Current returns the element that it is set to,
>   even if the enumerator is already invalidated.
>   (Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Yes, I've just encountered the same problem and used the same fix. I noticed that when I split get-childitem from remove-item, it took much longer to start removing items. This suggests that get-childitem pipes the first result to the next operation (remove-item in this case) as soon as it's available and continues after it completes.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you're removing a folder starting with .hg, which in turn contains a file starting with .hg, but that file no longer exists?

Answer (score 1):

I expect Antony is correct - using the -recurse on the gci will enumerate both files and directories that match ".hg*".  The directory will be returned first. Then remove-item deletes the directory first, and the -force switch deletes all the files in it.  Then it tries to delete the files that were in that directory that match ".hg*" (that were there when the gci ran) but they're gone now.  This should stop the errors:

```
gci ".hg*" -recurse | select -expand fullname | sort length -desc | remove-item -force
```

Sorting the full names in descending order of length insures that no matched parent directory is deleted before all the matched files in that directory are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The following will restrict its deletions to files only, and exclude folders.

```
gci -rec -filter ".hg*" | Where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $false} | remove-item -recurse -force
```

Then run it again, by deleting the folders:

```
gci -rec -filter ".hg*" | Where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $true} | remove-item -recurse -force
```

Comment: Why not delete the folders only?  I don't think Mercurial generates any files like that outside the .hg folders.